# Drupal 8 is unable to find DefaultWidget for custom field

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have created a custom field for my Drupal 8 app. The field name is called office address and should hold a complete address (address line 1, address line 2, city, state_code, zip_code, country code). It also has a config form which allows for the admin to decide which countries are available to select from.

Also, there is a service provider called CountryStateService, which provides a list of countries and their respective states.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/modules
  /office_address
    /config
      /install
        office_address.settings.yml
      /schema
        office_address.settings.yml
    /src
      /Form
        ConfigForm.php
      /Plugin
        /Field
          /FieldFormatter
            OfficeAddressDefaultFormatter.php
          /FieldType
            OfficeAddress.php
          /FieldWidget
            OfficeAddressDefaultWidget.php
      CountryStateService.php
  office_address.info.yml
  office_address.links.menu.yml
  office_address.permissions.yml
  office_address.routing.yml
  office_address.services.yml
```

The file src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/OfficeAddressDefaultWidget.php looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\office_address\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'OfficeAddressDefaultWidget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "OfficeAddressDefaultWidget",
 *   label = @Translation("Office Address"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "OfficeAddress"
 *   }
 * )
 */

class OfficeAddressDefaultWidget extends WidgetBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // my custom code here
  }
}
```

The file src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/OfficeAddress.php looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\office_address\Plugin\Field\FieldType\OfficeAddress
 */
namespace Drupal\office_address\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'Office Address' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "OfficeAddress",
 *   label = @Translation("Office Address"),
 *   description = @Translation("Stores an address."),
 *   category = @Translation("Custom"),
 *   default_widget = "OfficeAddressDefaultWidget",
 *   default_formatter = "OfficeAddressDefaultFormatter"
 * )
 */

class OfficeAddress extends FieldItemBase {
  // some code here
}
```

The extension installs without problems and the config form is usable, with the values getting saved and retrieved correctly. The problem appears when trying to add the OfficeAddress field to an existing content type.

The following error is issued:

> There was a problem creating field Office address: The "OfficeAddressDefaultWidget" plugin does not exist.

I do believe I have checked spelling everywhere and also file placement should be correct. I have created a similar module in the past which worked with the same file/directory structure (the name was Location instead of Office Address and there was no config form, nor any service providers involved). I've hit a wall at this point...

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a typo on my part in the directory structure. So this cost me a whole day.

Important note for whoever seems to be struggling with apparent nonsensical errors from Drupal 8: quadruple check your spelling as far directories/files and namespaces are concern!